# Node.js - express - jade - compile SASS/LESS

Tags: node.js, sass, less, express

Anyone have a *really* newbie guide to nodejs - express - SASS/LESS? I have not been able to get this working. The example I have now is a bareboned as possible..

```
var express = require('express'),
    less = require('less'),
    app = express.createServer();

var pub_dir = __dirname + '/public';

app.configure(function(){ 
    app.use(express.compiler({ src: pub_dir, enable: ['less'] }));
    app.use(express.staticProvider( pub_dir ));
};

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

The file `style.css.less` is located in `pub_dir`, I can access that directly, and the styling is

```
@brand_color: #4D926F;
body {
  color: @brand_color;
}
```

As far as I understand, the compilation is supposed to happen on start-up, and a css file will be generated in the `src`-dir, as dest is not specified.
My server runs fine, but regardless of how many ways I have tried messing around with the dirnames, directories and names of the LESS/SASS files (and their respective LESS/SASS content) I cannot get this working. Darn! Help.

Comment: Of course... make the src directory write-accesible... F(*&=)

Answer (score 13):

I'm also a newb trying to get this setup. I have tried a few snippets I found until I finally noticed that express has an 'express' command that sets up a new project.

Try `express -c less` to create a sample project with LESS as the CSS engine.

This should create the required directories. The new css files will be served from your static directory.

The configuration is:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
  app.use(express.bodyDecoder());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: Yup, it worked for my sass case. I used following command `express myapp -c sass`
Besides creating app with express structure, it also added node-sass-middleware settings to my app.

Answer (score 2):

Your setup is the standard setup for [readymade](http://poulejapon.github.com/readymade/). Make sure that less compiler is installed on your system though.

`npm install lessjs readymade`

And then add the following to your server.js

`app.use(require('readymade').middleware({root: "public"}));`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar question:
[Node.js + Express.js. How to RENDER less css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618257/node-js-express-js-how-to-render-less-css)

you can also check out the guide on the [ExpressJS Website](http://ExpressJs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Two projects which could make your life easier

1. [Buildr: The (Java|Coffee)Script and (CSS|Less) (Builder|Bundler|Packer|Minifier|Merger|Checker)](https://github.com/balupton/buildr.npm)
2. [DocPad: Pre-processor provider and template empowerer for Express.js apps](https://github.com/bevry/docpad)

Comment: @SamHasler thanks for that, yeah less4client got deprecated in favor of DocPad. Updated the link to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on express 4.x and using SASS. Here is a snippet part I'm using for styles (mind the comments):

```
var express = require('express'),
    // ... other packages
    sass = require('node-sass');

// ...
var app = express();
// ...
// Commented this default express generator line:
// app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//
// Because of some bug the node-sass (http://git.io/eItWzA) does not scan the correct folders,
// so I have both .scss and final .css in one /public/css/ folder
app.use(
    sass.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/public/', // where the sass files are 
        dest: __dirname + '/public/', // where css should go
    })
);

// ... rest of app
```

Here is a gist for it: http://git.io/Vr9KJA