# Node.js + Express.js. How to RENDER less css?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, less

I am unable to render less css in my express workspace.
Here is my current configuration **(my css/less files** are in **'public/stylo/')** :

```
app.configure(function()
{
    app.set('views'      , __dirname + '/views'         );
    app.set('partials'   , __dirname + '/views/partials');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade'                       );
    app.use(express.bodyDecoder()   );
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public/stylo', enable: ['less']}));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Here is my **main.jade file** :

```
!!!
html(lang="en")
     head
         title Yea a title
         link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="/stylo/main.less")
         link(rel="stylesheet", href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Droid+Sans|Droid+Sans+Mono|Ubuntu|Droid+Serif")
         script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js")
         script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js")
     body!= body
```

here is my **main.less css** :

```
@import "goodies.css";

body 
{
    .googleFont;
    background-color     :  #000000;
    padding              :  20px;
    margin               :  0px;

    > .header
    {
        border-bottom    :  1px solid #BBB;
        background-color :  #f0f0f0;
        margin           :  -25px -25px 30px -25px; /* important */
        color            :  #333;
        padding          :  15px;
        font-size        :  18pt;
    }
}
```

AND here is my **goodies.less css** :

```
.rounded_corners(@radius: 10px)
{    
    -moz-border-radius   :  @radius;
    -webkit-border-radius:  @radius;
    border-radius        :  @radius;
}
.shadows(@rad1: 0px, @rad2: 1px, @rad3: 3px, @color: #999)
{
    -webkit-box-shadow   :  @rad1 @rad2 @rad3 @color;
    -moz-box-shadow      :  @rad1 @rad2 @rad3 @color;
    box-shadow           :  @rad1 @rad2 @rad3 @color;
}
.gradient (@type: linear, @pos1: left top, @pos2: left bottom, @color1: #f5f5f5, @color2: #ececec)
{
    background-image     :  -webkit-gradient(@type, @pos1, @pos2, from(@color1), to(@color2));
    background-image     :  -moz-linear-gradient(@color1, @color2);
}
.googleFont
{
    font-family          :  'Droid Serif';
}
```

Cool deal. Now: **I have installed less via npm** and I had heard from another post that @imports should reference the `.css` not the `.less`. In any case, I have tried the **combinations** of switching `.less` for `.css` in the jade and less files with no success.

If you can help or have the solution I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Note:**  The jade portion works fine if I enter any ol' `.css`.
**Note2:** The less compiles if I use lessc via command line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Gosh, that stuff is very inconsistent in how the paths work, however I found out how you can get it to work.

The first problem is with your paths, both `compiler` and `staticProvider`, compiler needs to use `/public` and is will hook into all requests below that. If you don't do that, the compiler will try to use a path like `/public/stylo/stylo`.

The second problem lies with the `@import` in `main.less` file and the fact that less compiler is stupid and does not handle relative imports.

Using `@import "/public/stylo/goodies.css";` in your `main.less` will make it work.

Filed a Bug for the relative path issue with `less`:
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/issue/177

Comment: THANKS!!  I changed compiler to "app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }));"   But when the html/jade is pointed to a .less file, it does not interpret it to a .css file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh, got it to work! My jade file had to point to a .css file, and the less associated will be compiled! THANKS FOR THE HELP!! :D

Comment: One more thing, the @import should not have an extension. So: "@import "/public/stylo/goodies";"

Comment: now that you have it working, is there any way to pass an argument to express.compiler() that would make the output minified? along the lines of: parser.parse('.class { width: 1 + 1 }', function (e, tree) {
    tree.toCSS({ compress: true }); // Minify CSS output
})

Comment: Express 3.0.0 now includes a different middleware for compiling LESS. The original `compiler` middleware was removed from Connect which Express is based on. The new middleware is `less-middleware` and works pretty much the same way as the old one, but includes things like compressing the CSS output.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to minify the outputted css, I found that the built in compiler (from the connect module) was missing the compress option. So rather than writing my own middleware compiler for it. I overwrote the connect less compiler in my app.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var less;

express.compiler.compilers.less.compile = function (str, fn) {
    if (!less) less = require("less");                                                      
    try {
        less.render(str, { compress : true }, fn);
    } catch (err) {
        fn(err);
    }
};

app.use(express.compiler({ src: publicdir, enable: ['less'] }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler only compiles the file if its mtime is changed.

Lets say you have:

```
// A.less
@import "B.css";
```

and

```
// B.less
body {
  background: #f00;
}
```

I now I modify `B.less`, A will not be recompiled!

I have a pull request waiting since months, you can use my fork compiler instead of the master one.

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/pull/167

Comment: Thanks for that insight! That is a terrible bug. I will keep this in mind, but my "a.less" file won't compile either on any request.

Comment: I just tested this and you are correct. Wow! That's really bad!

Comment: Imports are typically bad for performance so are avoided.  I am assuming that bug slipped through since it is not best practice :-)
References:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#AvoidCssImport
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 0):

Two projects which could make your life easier

1. [Buildr: The (Java|Coffee)Script and (CSS|Less) (Builder|Bundler|Packer|Minifier|Merger|Checker)](https://github.com/balupton/buildr.npm)
2. [Less4Clients: Express.js extension to render LessCSS (.less) files server-side :)](https://github.com/balupton/less4clients.npm)

Answer (score 0):

I've published a [package on GitHub called node-kickstart-example](http://github.com/semu/node-kickstart-example) which uses a handy pre-configured express with enabled jade template rendering and less stylesheet processing. Use npm to install [kickstart](http://github.com/semu/node-kickstart), place your jade templates in `views/` and your less files in `assets/styles/` and your good to go…

Matt Sain's solution for generating compressed css files with less and express is in included in [kickstart](http://github.com/semu/node-kickstart).